# iOS OpenGL ES VBO weird rendering

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es

I'm not familiar with OpenGL but i have to improve code from other people. The problem, that they copied vertex data every draw call that cause very CPU intensive work. Now i'm trying to rewrite it to use VBO. New code is drawing but there is some weird size problem. Jigsaw pieces are bigger, sometimes exactly the same as an old code.

I understand that VBO is just creates buffer once inside GPU memory. But iw's obviously something wrong with it. Look i have pieces rendered with this code:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, background);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, sizeof(indicies)/sizeof(indicies[0]), GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, indicies);
```

And shadow with next code:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, sizeof(indicies)/sizeof(indicies[0]), GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, indicies);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

And result is next:
[image: Weird render problem]

As you see 2 pieces are stacked together but the shadow is rendered wrong. What can cause of this weird problem?

**UPDATE**
Piece of code where i create buffer:

```
glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(background), background, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

Comment: Are there different shaders for the pieces vs the shadow?  Maybe the problem exists there.

Comment: Pieces will be the same i just didnt change code for the pieces to show difference.

Comment: It might be a scaling/matrix problem ... try a glFlush after each glDrawElements (will run slower ... but you may see some differences)